# JS. How do I call a function that iterates through an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, for-loop, if-statement

Disclaimer: this is a homework assignment.
I'm not sure if I have set up my code right. Is this the correct way to call a function that iterates through an array? The document write is not showing anything.

```
var main = new Array ( );
main[0] = new Array (90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99);
main[1] = new Array (80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89);
main[2] = new Array (70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79);
main[3] = new Array (60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69);
main[4] = new Array (50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59);

//function declared
function getGrade(x) {
  var grade
  //inside the function, if/else statement
  if (x >= 90) {
    grade = "A";
  } else if (x >= 80) {
    grade = "B";
  } else if (x >= 70) {
    grade = "C";
  } else if (x >= 60) {
    grade = "D";
  } else {
    grade = "F";
  }
  return grade
};

// for loop 
for (i = 0; i < main.length; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < main[i].length; j++) {
    document.write("David's number grade is" + main[i][j] + "and letter grade is a " + Getgrade(main[i]));
 }
};
```

Comment: The function is called `getGrade()` so calling it with `Getgrade()` won't work (JS is case sensitive.) You can debug these things yourself if you open the browser's console (https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-do-i-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) and look at the error messages.

Answer (score 1):

Change this to `getGrade`

```
document.write("David's numbe..." + main[i][j] + "..." + getGrade(main[i][j]));
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two mistakes in your code.

1. You called the `getGrade` function as `Getgrade`. A typo.
2. Your `getGrade` function expects a number argument but you are passing an array value `main[i]`. You need to change it to `main[i][j]` so that the proper value in this two-dimensional array is passed to the function.

Update the line inside the loops to below to fix it:

```js
document.write("David's number grade is " + main[i][j] + " and letter grade is a " + getGrade(main[i][j]) + '\n');
```

Comment: Perfect answer!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for mentioning this is homework, I treated it that way and want to show you what I think is important (caution: that might not coincide with what your teacher thinks :))

If you want to play with Javascript, have a look at the repl.it web site. It's free and you can very easily run code and see what happens. Which leads to lesson number 1, don't just write code in a text editor and assume it'll run. If you can't test what you're doing, what you're doing is virtually useless. Spend the time to setup an environment where it's easy to play around. Repl.it allows quick turn around to test and it gives proper error messages right next to your code when you do something wrong. All helpful to save you frustration.

Here's my version as illustration, can still be improved but I wanted to keep it similar to what you did:

```
// Scores to test
const points = [
  [90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99],
  [80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89],
  [70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79],
  [60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69],
  [50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59]
];

// Returns a letter score based on a number score
function getGrade( x ) {
  if (x >= 90) return "A";
  if (x >= 80) return "B";
  if (x >= 70) return "C";
  if (x >= 60) return "D";
  return "F";
};

for (let i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < points[i].length; j++) {
    console.log("David's number grade is " + points[i][j] + " and letter grade is a " + getGrade(points[i][j]));
  }
};
```

What do I think you should learn from this:

1. Clarity is king. When you write code it's not because you understand it today that it's good code. Write it in such a way that you'll still understand what happens three years from now when you're hung over. While code might be functionally the same, that doesn't mean it's equally good.
2. If you're writing comments (probably because your teacher said you should), write real comments. Writing "function definition" above a function doesn't add any value. Real developers are lazy, and avoid doing things that don't add value. Write a comment that explains what the function does instead. If you can't think of a good comment, either try harder or don't write a comment at all.
3. If you continue to write code and read about code on the Internet you'll see all kinds of almost-religious statements. Having a function with multiple return values is one such topic I've encountered. Frankly, I don't care, I go for what seems the most legible to me (again, not now, three years from now when I have no recollection of having ever written this code).
4. Break things in smaller pieces. Asking "why does this write not generate anything" is the essential question any developer faces all day long. Break the problem down in smaller pieces. See if you can write the number grades, without the letters. Then add your function. If you would have done that, you would have noticed things broke at that point and that should give you a clue that it's the function that is wrong somehow.

On another note, who decided there is no "E" letter grade? That definitely was not a programmer.

Answer (score 0):

modify getGrade function when iterates

```js
var main = new Array ( );
main[0] = new Array (90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99);
main[1] = new Array (80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89);
main[2] = new Array (70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79);
main[3] = new Array (60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69);
main[4] = new Array (50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59);

console.log(main);

//function declared
function getGrade(x) {
  var grade;
  //inside the function, if/else statement
  if (x >= 90) {
    grade = "A";
  } else if (x >= 80) {
    grade = "B";
  } else if (x >= 70) {
    grade = "C";
  } else if (x >= 60) {
    grade = "D";
  } else {
    grade = "F";
  }
  return grade
};


// for loop 
for (i = 0; i < main.length; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < main[i].length; j++) {
    document.write("David's number grade is" + main[i][j] + "and letter grade is a " + getGrade(main[i][j]));
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what a strange way to code!
while it's simple like this:

```js
var main = 
  [ [90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]
  , [80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89]
  , [70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79]
  , [50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59]
  ]

const getGrade=x=>[...'FABCD'][[90,80,70,60].findIndex(e=>(x>=e))+1]

main.forEach(row=>row.forEach(v=>{
  document.write(`David's number grade is ${v} and letter grade is a ${getGrade(v)} <br>`);
}))
```